# Facebook Ads Insights API - Requesting Website URL Parameter

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm in the process of learning the Facebook Insights API, and fetching data at various levels (campaign, ad set, etc.). In the link below, you'll see a screenshot of Facebook's Business Manager, and the field for adding a Website URL destination. I'm interested in requesting this field in the Python Facebook Marketing Insights API.

[Facebook Business Manager - Ad Website URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SszdN.png)

I've searched for relevant fields in the Ads Insights documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/insights/), but still haven't had any luck. Is this the right place, or should I be looking elsewhere to fetch this information?

Comment: If anything, that would be a property of the ad itself, and not an insights metric.

Answer (score 0):

CBroe is right. I ended up having to make a 2nd api call using the creative_id from the object_story_spec:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/{CREATIVE_ID}/?fields=asset_feed_spec&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

?fields=asset_feed_spec will give you the website_url nested in link_urls.