# What's the API method to retrieve the destination website URL of a Facebook ad?

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-ads

(1) I need to extract the link inside a facebook ad. When creating a facebook ad , we need to fill in destination, where we need to fill website url, how can I get this value from some facebook api. Basically the link where the ad redirects to.
(2) Also, is there a way where I can get all attributes/properties of an ad, which were filled in while creating the ad, through some api, such as name, body, website_url.

The input that I can give is the ad_id

I have tried `https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/23855312168950236?fields=name api`, wherein I have passed name as a param, and the response is
`{     "name": "Testing fbp cookies",     "id": "23855312168950236" }`
. This response is fine.

As per the documentation,  I used object_url, link_url and a few other params as ,
`https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/23855312168950236?fields=object_url`,
but then the response changes to ,
`{     "error": {         "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (object_url) on node type (Ad)",         "type": "OAuthException",         "code": 100,         "fbtrace_id": "AiMmHEZkpParXv9soPnBPCg"     } }`

api cURL referred from - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/creative
query params list referred from - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative

also tried - [Facebook Ads Insights API - Requesting Website URL Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142298/facebook-ads-insights-api-requesting-website-url-parameter)
but same error

**
NOTE - I AM USING CREATIVE_ID AS THE AD_ID ITSELF**

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me:

```
params = {
    "fields": "asset_feed_spec", 
    "access_token": my_access_token,  # Replace with your actual access token
    "app_id": my_app_id  # Replace with your actual access token
}

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{0}".format(your_creative_id)
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(response.text)
```

The website_url is buried in the resulting asset_feed_spec JSON.   The FB docs are near impossible to follow and split across V2 and V3 of python and various SDK tooling.  Here's what got me to what I needed:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/ad-creative/asset-feed-spec/

Good luck!